# Change order of registered script files in yii

Tags: jquery, yii

I'm making a widget for a Yii application. The main layout view registers all the common script files such as jQuery and jQueryUI. In my widget I want to use a jQueryUI plugin that relies on jQueryUI already being loaded.

I know I can specify where on the page the script is included, but it seems a bit hit and miss to simply include it at the "end" - what if I have other script that I need to load after that plugin? How do I ensure they're loaded in the right order - anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You can specify the position. See the documentation for [registerScript](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript/#registerScript-detail) and/or [registerScriptFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript/#registerScriptFile-detail)

Comment: Thanks for the thought but I was aware of this. You can specify one of three places - POS_BEGIN, POS_END and POS_READY - that doesn't help if I need all my plugins to be loaded in POS_BEGIN, but some are coming from the main layout, and some from widgets.

Comment: I see, did you try browsing the source of the zii widgets?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the dependency feature in Yii [script packages](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#packages-detail). I was having [similar problem before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904761/registerpackage-depends-on-registerscriptfile).

For example you have script packages config like below,

```
'clientScript' => array(
  'packages' => array(
     'package1' => array(
          'basePath' => 'path.to.package1',
          'js' => array(
              'package1.js',
          ),
          'css' => array(
              'package1.css'
          ),
      ),
     'package2' => array(
          'basePath' => 'path.to.package2',
          'js' => array(
              'package2.js',
          ),
          'css' => array(
              'package2.css'
          ),
          'depends' => array(
                'package1',
          )
      ),
     'package3' => array(
          'basePath' => 'path.to.package3',
          'js' => array(
              'package3.js',
          ),
          'css' => array(
              'package3.css'
          ),
          'depends' => array(
                'package2',
          )
      ),
   )
)
```

In sample above, `package2` requires (depends) `package1` and `package3` requires `package2`. Let's say in your case, a widget uses `package2`, and the other script uses `package3`. Even if you don't render the widget, if you use `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('package3');`, it will automatically install the `package2` which then install the `package1` before `package2` (or won't install if the `package1` is already required by some scripts before.).