# Yii Make jQuery load first

Tags: jquery, yii, assets

Many modules, extensions or other things in Yii try to load jQuery from the asset manager. Which is fine, I've quit hardcoding the include and instead I am embracing 'registerCoreScript'.

The only issue is that it seems to be loading it near the bottom of the HEAD. I have a lot of other scripts and code that depend on jQuery, and they are loaded before it. How do I make sure that jQuery is the first thing loaded??

The truth is I don't understand how it's not the default behavior. jQuery doesn't depend on anything, but lots of scripts depend on it...

Comment: I don't think there's a way to alter the position within the head. I thought scripts got added to the DOM in the order they are declared in your php, is it not possible to move your `registerCoreScript` function above other script calls?

Comment: registerCoreScript is the first call I make, in my layout file, even before the opening `<html>`. After it I have a series of hardcoded javascripts and css.

Comment: content will be appended to anything you have in `<head>`, see my answer for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `packages` [property of CClientScript](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#packages-detail) component, and specify `depends`:

```php
Yii::app()->clientScript->addPackage('give-some-name-to-script', array(
    'baseUrl'=>'base URL for the script files', // or basePath
    'js'=>array(list of js files relative to basePath/baseUrl),
    'depends'=>array('jquery')
));
```

Or do it this in *config/main.php* configuration:

```php
'clientScript'=>array(
    'packages'=>array(
        'give-this-package-name'=>array(
            'basePath'=>'alias of the directory containing the script files',
            'js'=>array('first.js','second.js'),
            'depends'=>array('jquery')
    ),
)
```

And then use [`registerPackage`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerPackage-detail):

```php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('your-package-name');
```

This is the only way that this can be done, i think. Of course this requires you to either group your javascript into a package and give it some name, or declare each script as a package.

---

Related answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130907/720508) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9677546/720508)

Comment: by hardcoded javascript i assumed you meant: `<script type="text/javascript" src="some.js">` or did you actually mean : `<script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>` ?

Comment: I've got both. But you are right, I went with your approach, re-organizing all of my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use hardcoded `<script>` tags in you html
2. Put `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');` at the beginning of your `Controller::init()` function.
3. Include you own scripts using `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('....');`

Answer (score 0):

If the reference to hardcoded scripts in your comment means that you have `<script>` and `<style>` tags in your layout file in the `<head>`, then yes, using any of the Yii methods to register the script will result in that script coming last, as the Yii methods append the javascript to any existing content in the `<head>` ([read the source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/CClientScript.php#L350) if you want to verify).

Ideally, you should externalize the javascript into a separate file and load the file using [registerScriptFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScriptFile-detail).  This makes things cleaner and easier to maintain.

Alternatively, you could use [registerScript()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail), but that can be difficult to read/maintain.

When using these methods, items will be added in the order the methods are called.